# Don't fetching in subselect same entites multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a problem with fetching by Id of a subselected entity

Here the structure

```
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    


    //Other class members;
    }
```

```
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    

    @ValueRestriction("NOTNULL")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
    private C c;

    @ValueRestriction("NOTNULL")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private A a;
    //Other class members;
}
```

```
public class C {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c")
    @Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<B> bs;
   

    @ValueRestriction("NOTNULL")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private A a;
    //Other class members;
}
```

So when we fetch over hibernate

```
 em().find(B.class, id);
```

the Hibernate query also fetches the columns of A in the C entity.
This lead in a bigger Entitystructure to an

```
target lists can have at most 1664 entries
```

(This is a simple demonstration)

In our case we need the references of Entity A in all of these sub Entities

How can we prevent hibernate to fetch the same object multiple times if it is the ame.

In our cases A will always be the SAME in Entity B and Entity C. The Case that Entity B has a different A Entity than in the C Entity is in our structure not possible.

Comment: Do yu have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation in all of your classes. That is quite important when using ORM. Also your code is probably wrong as `C` probably has a list of `B` and not a list of `C`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Yes we have implemented both in each entity

Comment: Have changed it above, was a typo.

Comment: The problem is, that the hibernate query which is generated 
fetches A through of B and also fetches A in C as a separate column. 

B and C depend on A. 
In our software architecture A of B should everytimes the same in C

Comment: You know that, but hibernate doesn't (and will not know that) so it has to do what you told it to do and that is to fetch it. To make matters worse The C belonging to the B might belong to other B which belong to other C which will be loaded as well. When using `mappedBy` you shouldn't be using a `@JoinColumn` I believe. See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

are you sure?
So usually map parent and child in this case. 
shorturl.at/tEHMQ

Okay it is okay that hibernate do it as is do. But maybe there is a possibility to give a hint to the query?

Or how would you solve this problem.
let me give you a real assosiation:

You have a Shop entity. Each shop have items to sell, and orders which have been purchased, also paymethods and so on. Items, as Orders, Paymethods have a relation to the Shop. 
When you fetch the orders by id, it also have fetches the shop members in item, paymethod and so on

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` by default do eager fetching. Switch to lazy fetching `@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)` to avoid this.